# How to use magento api with iOS app

Tags: api, magento, magento-1.9

I want to use Magento custom API with iOS app.
What option we have to develop such a application.Magento SOAP or REST or anything else is useful in this case.
Please suggest me best way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup API roles and users in Magento. After that you can use these credentials to fetch and update data in Magento.

Check this http://www.codepetals.com/setup-your-magento-store-for-integration-with-mobile-app-or-an-erp/